# Is there a way to update graph data without the graph flashing/flickering in ant-design/charts?

Tags: react-native, charts, antd

I'm using ant-design/charts in react to draw x, y points as line, data is read from a socket, so I need to add points to the data of the Line and update the graph on screen every second. The problem is I can't find a way to update the data and making the new points visible on screen without having react redrawing the whole Line causing the line to flickers. How can I add new points to the line without the flickers with ant-design/charts or is it not possible?

The examples I've looked at shows how to visualize data at hand and therefore only update once in the beginning.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this @klau?